# Code Lost by using Git (GitLab) and Unknown Message Shows Staging merge into Staging

Tags: git, gitlab

I am facing an error on GIT (GitLab). Me and my senior started working and after weeks, we notice that our code isn't properly managed. At point 1, my senior added 80 lines in a file but when I pull and push the code, those 80 lines removed (I first pull than push and didn't' see any conflict) by using this single line command

```
> git status && git add -A && git commit -m "Updates" && git pull origin staging && git push origin staging
```

can someone please tell me what's going wrong ? this thing is making me worry because because this seems that I removed the code intentionally, also we didn't know how many times this happened

One more thing, when I lost the code, the message of that commit is

```
Merge branch 'staging' of http://www.example.com into staging
```

The commit seems suspicious to me, can someone please explain it ? how can a branch with same name is merge within itself ?

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: About the merge message "staging of http" is the remote branch of that name. It is merged with your local branch.
The "merge" is (most likely) created by `git pull` (see the pull docs, you can change that). So the merge is created after your `git add && git commit`.

Comment: Suggestions: 1. do not call a branch "staging". Staging is a concept of git, and if you give it another meaning you're going to confuse and get confused. 2. Spend time writing actual commit messages. Do an internet search for what makes a good git commit message. You're going to be thankful about this later. "Updates" does not qualify as a good commit message.

Comment: At point (2) you made yet another commit. Maybe you removed the lines? (Maybe you had the file open in an editor and saved it / Maybe you git stashed push/pop them ?)

Comment: Anyway, that first chain of command you use guarantees two things: 1) you'll break other things in the future and 2) you won't understand what you're doing with git. I'd suggest you read a few tutorials and use git as a real tool, not just copy-pasting a mysterious command to "save project".

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you understand what is happening behind `git pull`?

`pull` = `fetch` + `merge`.

When you do `git pull origin staging`, you are:

1. fetching the branch `staging` of `origin`
2. merging it **into your current local branch**

Then at the subsequent `push`, you push **your local branch** into the branch `staging` of `origin`.

Don't forget that your local branch `staging` is not necessarily the same as the branch `staging` of `origin`. That is what you are seeing in that commit message.

I recommend that you change your workflow.

As a first step, these can help limit confusion:

- update your local branch to always mirror that of the remote repo. This means that you need to checkout that local branch before pulling from origin. `git checkout local_branch`, then `git pull origin local_branch`. Do not chain the commands with `&&`, just make it in two steps while you learn.
- when you make new commits to that local branch, and they're ready to be shared with other people, push them to the remote repo: `git push origin local_branch`. Make sure you have the correct local branch checked out!
- if you have a new branch that you want to mirror into the remote repo, push and set upstream with `-u`: `git push -u origin branch_name`. This creates the branch in the remote repo, and sets up your current branch as remote tracking for that remote branch. Name it the same (not technically necessary, but good to avoid confusion).

Sharing branches among several developers is possible and powerful, but can get a bit more complicated with conflicts, diverging history... I would recommend, while getting used to git, to keep branches personal. Have your branch only for you. Once you're done, ask for a review. Since you're using gitlab, let gitlab handle the merge to `main` for you.